# Вывод кол-ва участников группы онлайн. API

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Как можно получать кол-во онлайн участников определенной группы, используя методы API?
Пробовал слать запрос сюда:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.search?count=1&c[online]=1&c[group]=26087256&access_token=***
```

пробовал слать сюда:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?count=1&c[online]=1&group_id=26087256&access_token=***
```

Но толку ноль.. в первом случае возвращается какое-то непонятное число, во втором случае возвращается общее кол-во пользователей.

Comment: что-то никто даже не ответил

Comment: А что отвечать? Меня всегда удивляют вопросы уровня "а как сделать XYZ?", когда вся документация по API находится в свободном доступе.  

BTW, зачем вы явно задаёте `count=1` при том, что хотите получить **количество участников**? Что такое `c[online]`?

Comment: @klopp count=1 - это кол-во выводимых пользователей. В документации не сказано как выводить тех, кто онлайн.
c[online] - это метка в поиске вк. Но тут она почему-то не работает.

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю, вы задаёте лимит в 1, в то время как хотите получить всех пользователей, подходящих под критерий. Зачем?

Дальше. `c[online]` - это фигня какая-то, в документации по `users.search` этого нет (а есть просто `online=1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы присутствуете на сеансе художественного чтения вслух [документации по методу users.search](https://vk.com/dev/users.search):

```
/* ненужное пропускаем  */

online
    1 — только в сети, 0 — все пользователи. 
    флаг, может принимать значения 1 или 0

/* ненужное пропускаем  */

group_id
    идентификатор группы, среди пользователей которой необходимо проводить поиск. 
    положительное число
```

OK, тянем ручонки к клавиатуре:

```
$ wget -O ./vk.txt "https://api.vk.com/method/users.search?online=1&group_id=26087256&access_token=не_скажу"
```

Тадамс, фокус-покус!

```
response: {
count: 1588,
items: [{
id: 36084588,
first_name: 'Денис',
last_name: 'Задворный',
screen_name: 'denis_zoner_id36084588',
photo: 'https://pp.vk.me/c4565/u36084588/e_23b06c97.jpg'
}, {
id: 52701089,
first_name: 'Марина',
last_name: 'Березуцкая',
screen_name: 'marinacskaska',
photo: 'https://pp.vk.me/c617130/v617130089/1617a/aH2v02QzbBs.jpg'
}, {
id: 94260995,
first_name: 'Лили',
last_name: 'Аксёнова',
screen_name: 'lily_aksenova',
photo: 'https://pp.vk.me/c616921/v616921995/152e7/NXDiIWyTaCs.jpg'
}, {
id: 124237921,
first_name: 'Александр',
last_name: 'Пимуков',
screen_name: 'mr.alex_great',
photo: 'https://pp.vk.me/c618518/v618518921/cb65/5NiNHdl-aZY.jpg'
}, {
id: 36830566,
first_name: 'Виктор',
last_name: 'Зубко',
screen_name: 'idposthardcore666',
photo: 'https://pp.vk.me/c617927/v617927566/bd23/lX1eRgC3FzA.jpg'
}]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Берите количество участников и обновляйте средствами JS, каждые n секунд\минут. И будет вам какой-никакой онлайн-вывод :)